# Typecasting a struct to unsigned char* in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, casting, char

I have the below struct in my program.

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
struct data
{
BYTE a;
BYTE b;
BYTE c;
};
```

some lines late..... I create an instance of the struct

```
data buffer[100][100];
```

later in the program I have to typecast the "buffer" instance to char * in order to be used by another function.

```
int bmp_generator(char *filename, int width, int height, BYTE* data)
{
BITMAPFILEHEADER bmp_head;
BITMAPINFOHEADER bmp_info;
int size=width*height*3;

bmp_head.bfType=0x4D42;
bmp_head.bfSize=size + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmp_head.bfReserved1=bmp_head.bfReserved2=0;
bmp_head.bfOffBits=bmp_head.bfSize-size;

bmp_info.biSize=40;
bmp_info.biWidth=width;
bmp_info.biHeight=height;
bmp_info.biPlanes=1;
bmp_info.biBitCount=24;// bits per pixel
bmp_info.biCompress=0;
bmp_info.biSizeImage=size;
bmp_info.biXPelsPerMeter=0;
bmp_info.biYPelsPerMeter=0;
bmp_info.biClrUsed=0;
bmp_info.biClrImportant=0;

FILE *fp;
if (!(fp=fopen(filename,"wb"))) return 0;

fwrite(&bmp_head,1, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), fp);
fwrite(&bmp_info,1,sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), fp);
fwrite (data, 1, size, fp);
fclose(fp);

return 1;
}
```

[some lines later]

```
bmp_generator("./test.bmp", 512, 512, (BYTE*)buffer);
```

However, when I run the above code the gcc compiler gives me a warning saying
"warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]"

can someone help me out with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That's not an instance of the struct. That's 10,000 instances of the struct.

Comment: We cannot answer this question without your [MCVE], but the problem  has nothing to do with `buffer` or the type `data` — it relates to how you're handling the _first_ argument to the `THEfUNCTION` function/macro, as that's where the string constant/literal is. Please show your [MCVE] and abstract away all unrelated/unnecessary distractions. (This is debugging that you should already have performed.)

Comment: The error there has nothing to do with your `data` structure as far as the code you posted shows. We would need to see the signature of the (obnoxiously capitalized) `THEfUNCTION`.

Comment: I have added the complete function. the reason why I did not put the question is because then people would start suggesting to use libraries in order to create bitmap, while i cannot do so in the project that i am involved with. Hence THEfUNCTION.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert char\* to const char\* in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637171/convert-char-to-const-char-in-c)

Comment: "later in the program I have to typecast the "buffer" instance to char *" - So when the compiler decides that it wants to add padding into your struct because <reasons>, your cast will be completely broken and you'll be feeding rubbish into your function.  Make it a byte array and you'll never have to worry about padding or nasty nasty casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is not about the `struct` but about the first argument of `THEfUNCTION`. It seems that the function takes `char*` as the first argument. Now, the string literal you pass as the argument is converted to `char*` but this kind of conversion is deprecated.

Generally, a good thing to do is to convert string literals to `const char*` as long as you have control of the signature of the function you're using.

Comment: Note that since C++11 the conversion isn't merely deprecated. It's Ill-formed.